# What does "Number of locked synchronizers = 1" in a StackTrace mean?

Tags: java, debugging, exception, logging

I am currently working on some code that I inherited. When executing it, a lot of exceptions get logged to the console, where one such exception would look like this:

```
["bg-thread-0" Id=28 RUNNABLE
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:56)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:677)
    -  locked java.util.zip.ZipFile@67369c20
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:413)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.bundlefile.BundleEntry.getBytes(BundleEntry.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:455)
    ...

    Number of locked synchronizers = 1
    - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@66e5b079

]
```

I am using [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch) for the logging. Now I have no idea where that exception is generated or logged, because that information is cut by the `...`.
I also have no idea what it means. I guess it's got something to do with deadlocks (because of the `Number of locked synchronizers = 1`), but I don't know for sure.

So my question is: How to proceed here? What does that exception mean, how do I debug and find it and how do I resolve it? I really have no clue and would appreciate any hints. Thanks!

Comment: That looks like more like a thread dump than a regular stacktrace.  You get those when something sends a SIGQUIT signal to the JVM process,

Comment: @StephenC: If so, by what mechanism does the thread get dumped? How do I intercept/debug/analyze to find the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like more like a Java thread dump than a regular stacktrace.  (I would expect to see one of those for each thread.)

You (typically) get a Java thread dump  when something external to the JVM sends a SIGQUIT signal to the JVM process.

This Q&A has some ideas on how to track down the source of unexpected signals:

- https://superuser.com/questions/573410/what-killed-my-process

One suggested approach is to use the Linux Audit system (see `man auditctl`), and another is to use systemtap.  (I don't have experience with either ... but I did spot some systemtap examples for tracking down signals here: https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/).

---

For what it is worth, a "synchronizer" is building block class that is used to implement locks; see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html.  The line:

```
Number of locked synchronizers = 1
```

is effectively saying that that the thread is currently holding one lock.  Note that Oracle don't formally document what the thread dump means, and they apparently say that the format may change across versions / releases.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I don't think this is correct. First of all, those dumps or stack traces or whatever they are appear in the regular console, i.e. the execution output of the program. Second, they appear deterministically when starting the program, so I don't think other processes are involved. Third, using JStack the output (which gets send to a separate console) looks more like that: "Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007f84e5014800 nid=0x3903 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

Comment: 1)  Thread dumps go to the console too.  2) The signals could be coming from a process launched by the JVM, or from the JVM launcher.  3) The format of thread stack dumps is Java version specific.

Comment: If this is not a thread dump, I'd be interested hear what it actually is.  Please self-answer the question if you figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful intput. I found it after all (although it took me a while).

Comment: I'll accept your answer, since that helped me find the solution I posted in a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found it!

Somewhere deep in the code I found the following:

```
for (ThreadInfo threadInfo : ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().dumpAllThreads(true, true)) {
      System.out.println(threadInfo);
}
```

So it was a Thread Dump after all, but one that was triggered internally. Thanks for the answers!